# Apollo graphql prisma create mutation give one to many error

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I tried to create track record the have one to many relation with user table and I got the following error.

> An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. No 'User' record(s) (needed to inline the relation on 'Track' record(s)) was found for a nested connect on one-to-many relation 'TrackToUser'."

I want who is created this record. So that I added the track to user as following in my schema.

I can create artist and album record.

May I know why I got this issue.

```
model Genre {
  id     String  @id @default(cuid())
  name   String  @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  albums Album[]
  @@map("genres")
}

model SongWriter {
  id     String  @id @default(cuid())
  name   String  @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  tracks Track[]

  @@map("songwriters")
}

model Artist {
  id              String    @id @default(cuid())
  name            String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  bio             String?   @db.VarChar(1024)
  profile_picture String    @db.VarChar(512)
  albums          Album[]
  tracks          Track[]
  active          Boolean   @default(true)
  user            User      @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id         String
  created_at      DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at      DateTime? @updatedAt

  @@map("artists")
}

model Album {
  id          String    @id @default(cuid())
  title       String    @db.VarChar(255)
  album_cover String    @db.VarChar(512)
  description String?   @db.VarChar(5120)
  released    Int       @default(1900)
  artists     Artist[]
  genres      Genre[]
  tracks      Track[]
  active      Boolean   @default(true)
  user        User      @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id     String
  created_at  DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime? @updatedAt

  @@map("albums")
}

model Track {
  id          String       @id @default(cuid())
  title       String       @db.VarChar(255)
  description String?      @db.VarChar(5120)
  mp3_url     String       @db.VarChar(1024)
  youtube_url String       @db.VarChar(1024)
  duration    Int          @default(0)
  artists     Artist[]
  album       Album        @relation(fields: [album_id], references: [id])
  album_id    String
  songWriters SongWriter[]
  active      Boolean      @default(true)
  user        User         @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id     String
  created_at  DateTime     @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime?    @updatedAt

  @@map("tracks")
}

model User {
   id              String    @id @default(cuid())
   name            String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
   password        String    @db.VarChar(512)
   profile_picture String?   @db.VarChar(512)
   role            Role      @default(USER)
   tokenVersion    Int       @default(0)
   artists         Artist[]
   albums          Album[]
   tracks          Track[]
   active          Boolean   @default(true)
   created_at      DateTime  @default(now())
   updated_at      DateTime? @updatedAt
   @@map("users")
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to create a Track record and all has worked properly, here you go the code snippet (I do not know if it is what you want):

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const saveData = async () => {
  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: 'The Best User',
      password: '123456',
      profile_picture: 'https://www.example.com/user.jpg',
      tokenVersion: 1,
    }
  })
  console.log('USER', user)
  const gnre = await prisma.genre.create({
    data: {
      name: 'The Best Genre',
    }
  })
  console.log('GENRE', gnre)
  const album = await prisma.album.create({
    data: {
      title: 'The Best Album',
      album_cover: 'https://www.example.com/album.jpg',
      description: 'This is the best album ever',
      released: 1,
      active: true,
      user: {
        connect: {
          id: user.id
        }
      },
      genres: {
        connect: {
          id: gnre.id
        }
      }
    }
  })
  console.log('ALBUM', album)
  const artist = await prisma.artist.create({
    data: {
      name: 'The Best Artist',
      bio: 'The best artist ever',
      profile_picture: 'https://www.example.com/artist.jpg',
      active: true,
      user: {
        connect: {
          id: user.id
        }
      }
    }
  })
  console.log('ARTIST', artist)
  const songWriter = await prisma.songWriter.create({
    data: {
      name: 'The Best Song Writer',
    }
  })
  console.log('SONG WRITER', songWriter)
  const track = await prisma.track.create({
    data: {
      title: 'The Best Track',
      description: 'The best track ever',
      mp3_url: 'https://www.example.com/track.mp3',
      youtube_url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
      duration: 1000,
      active: true,
      artists: {
        connect: {
          id: artist.id
        }
      },
      album: {
        connect: {
          id: album.id
        }
      },
      user: {
        connect: {
          id: user.id
        }
      },
      songWriters: {
        connect: {
          id: songWriter.id
        }
      }
    },
    include: {
      artists: true,
      album: true,
      user: true,
      songWriters: true,
    }
  })
  console.log('TRACK')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(track, null, 2));
}

saveData()
```

Here you go the result:

[image]

Comment: thank for nice example. Actually I did the same thing. My data structure is as same as your. After I log out and log in again, it is working fine now. I still have no idea, why this error occurred. So I am monitoring the issue.

Comment: cool and it was a pleasure!